# Multiple Select values to be exploded in SQL upload for MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select dropdown in my form

```
<select name="gs_details" required>
  <option value="">Please Select One</option>
  <option value="'1'_'2'">eTrack</option>
</select>
```

My SQL upload page has the following

```
$gs_details = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gs_details');
$parts = explode('_', $gs_details);
$group_id = $parts[0];
$user_id = $parts[1];
```

I then have 2 actions that need to be run to update and insert new row into MYSQL DB

```
UPDATE gs_user_objects SET group_id = '".$group_id."' WHERE imei = '$imei'
```

AND

```
INSERT INTO gs_user_objects SET
  user_id = '".$user_id."', imei = '".$imei."',
  group_id = '0', driver_id = '0', trailer_id = '0'
```

I am getting the following ***ERROR***

***You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1'' WHERE imei = '862011228002002'' at line 2Error: INSERT INTO gs_user_objects SET user_id = ''2'', imei = '862011228002002', group_id = '0', driver_id = '0', trailer_id = '0'***

What my aim is is to have the dropdown have two values and when I POST it to the php page to upload and update the values must be used in two different strings.

```
$group_id = 1
$user_id = 2
```

**Table Structure**

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| user_id | INT |
| group_id | INT |
| imei | VARC |
| driver_id | INT |
| trailer_id | INT |

Comment: kindly show table structure of "gs_user_objects "

Comment: Please show an [MCVE]

Comment: BTW: remove single quotes around numbers in your sql statement and learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries. Fixing this would have the incidental benefit of resolving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kindly remove single quote from value

```
<option value="1_2">eTrack</option>
```

since in your query you use single quote it is making it into double quote that might be the problem see this is the problem

```
INSERT INTO gs_user_objects SET user_id = ''2'',
```

Comment: this worked thank you I saw the "" in the error statement and was not sure how to remove it